# How do I use `srb rbi suggest-typed` without downgrading sigils?

Tags: sorbet

The Sorbet typechecker for Ruby has a utility, `srb rbi suggest-typed`, which will automatically update the `# typed:` sigils on each file. However, [as the Sorbet docs explain](https://sorbet.org/docs/faq#how-do-i-upgrade-sorbet), “currently, the suggestion process is fallible, and may suggest downgrading when it's not necessary.” I have a Sorbet-typed codebase that I’d like to try upgrading the types on (to “ratchet” any files that have been fully typed without having their sigil changed), but because it’s a very large codebase I don’t want to have to manually audit every file that’s changed. Is there a way to get Sorbet to only apply a change to the sigil if it’s an upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn’t seem to be any way to get Sorbet to do this itself. Instead, as a workaround, here are some instructions for using Git to only *commit* the changes that upgrade the sigil, and discard any changes that would be a downgrade.

1. Start with a clean working directory (make sure `git status` doesn’t show any changed files).
2. Run `srb rbi suggest-typed`. This will change a lot of sigils, both upgrading and downgrading them.
3. Produce a summary of the different kinds of changes that have been made:

   ```sh
   git diff --word-diff -U0 | grep '# typed: ' | sort | uniq -c
   ```

   ```
     36 # typed: [-false-]{+ignore+}
      8 # typed: [-false-]{+strict+}
     27 # typed: [-false-]{+true+}
     36 # typed: [-strict-]{+false+}
    150 # typed: [-true-]{+strict+}
     80 {+# typed: false+}
   ```
4. Use [`grepdiff`](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/patchutils/) to find each of the changes you **don’t** want, and pipe the result to `git checkout` to drop those changes (modify the below commands as needed for the changes you have gotten):

   ```sh
   git diff | grepdiff --output-matching=hunk --only-match=rem 'typed: false'  | grepdiff --only-match=add 'typed: ignore' --strip=1 | xargs git checkout --
   git diff | grepdiff --output-matching=hunk --only-match=rem 'typed: strict' | grepdiff --only-match=add 'typed: false'  --strip=1 | xargs git checkout --
   git diff | grepdiff --only-match=add 'typed: false' --strip=1 | xargs git checkout --
   ```
5. Rerun the summary command from step 3 to make sure the results include only what you want.
6. Commit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make creative use of `rubocop-sorbet` for this:

1. Add `rubocop-sorbet` if it isn't already in the `Gemfile`
2. Change `rubocop.yml` to something like:

```
---
inherit_from: .rubocop_todo.yml
inherit_mode:
  merge:
    - Include
require:
  - rubocop-sorbet
AllCops:
  DisabledByDefault: true
  Include:
    - '**/*/*.rbi'
Sorbet/FalseSigil:
  Enabled: true
Sorbet/IgnoreSigil:
  Enabled: true
Sorbet/StrictSigil:
  Enabled: true
Sorbet/StrongSigil:
  Enabled: true
Sorbet/TrueSigil:
  Enabled: true
```

3. Invoke `rubocop --auto-gen-config --exclude-limit 10000` (or some other sufficiently large number that prevents rubocop from disabling rules entirely)
4. Invoke `srb rbi suggest-typed`
5. Any downgraded files should now trigger rubocop violations. You can undo changes to these files with `rubocop -f fi | xargs git checkout --`
6. Also remember to revert any unwanted changes to `Gemfile`, `.rubocop.yml`, `.rubocop_todo.yml`, etc. before committing the result.

Comment: This is quite clever, but unfortunately rubocop is very slow—I just tried this on our monorepo (some tens of thousands of ruby files) and I think it took at least 6 hours to run. It also downgraded a file from `false` to `ignore`, though I didn't dig into why.

Comment: @Wolfgang you included `DisabledByDefault: true`, correct? I was able to inspect 3422 files in 30s on a 5yo MBP (on the rails repo).